# Excel: New Powerquery from Web (csv) doesnt work

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, csv, query, power-query

I want to build a worksheet where the user can input a Stock symbol and the balance sheet is automatically downloaded from morningstar to a table, and then some custom formulas are run on the data.

On github I found the hidden morningstar API:
https://gist.github.com/hahnicity/45323026693cdde6a116

E.g. to retrieve some financials, I use (in my browser):
http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?t=TWTR&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&number=3

Now I tried to start by building a query using *Data->New Query->From different source->From web*, I entered the URL and instead of seeing the actual csv-data as in my browser, a popup appears to actually open the file in a new Excel window. Even when trying to query a csv and entering the URL there, it doesnt work.

The popup looks like this:
[image]

I do NOT want to open this file, I want to query the csv data!

Any ideas why it doesnt work?
And how to make it actually work?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why downvote? Not a valid question?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a way for Excel to do what you wish natively; however, I have written a procedure that I used to use for downloading stock data. In my case I used to use yahoo.finance.com but you can modify this pretty easily for the site you are getting your stock data from:

```
Sub GetData()

Dim QuerySheet As Worksheet
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
Dim qurl As String
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet

range("C7").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
i = 7
qurl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + Cells(i, 1)
i = i + 1
While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    qurl = qurl + "+" + Cells(i, 1)
    i = i + 1
Wend
qurl = qurl + "&f=" + "nl1vhgd1rm4"

QueryQuote:
         With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=DataSheet.range("C7"))
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            .SaveData = True
        End With

        range("C7").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=range("C7"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False


'turn calculation back on
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 25.43
range("h2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I'll give it a shot. But why shouldnt it be possible? From what I understood is: Excel should be able to connect with Data which comes from the web (http:// address) isnt it? So why not a csv from a web address?

Comment: @tim I never said it wasn't possible just that I don't know how to. Perhaps a way exists out there. Plus I personally like code that I can customize to perform a task exactly how I want it done.